# wc_get_product always returns false

Tags: woocommerce

No matter what I do, I can't see to get wc_get_product function to return a product.

I have this code at present located at the bottom of my functions.php file:

```
function get_all_products() {
  $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'product',
             'posts_per_page' => -1,
     );
  return get_posts($args);
}

echo '<pre>';
$products = get_all_products();
$first_product = $products[0];
$_product = wc_get_product( $first_product->ID );
var_dump( $_product );
exit();
```

But it always returns

```
 bool(false)
```

Even if hardcode the value:

```
 $_product = wc_get_product( 9365 );
```

Still returns false.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    echo '<pre>';
    $products = get_all_products();
    $_product = wc_get_product( $first_product->ID );
    var_dump( $_product );
    exit();
});
```

this fixed it

Comment: how did that fix it? $first_product is never declared.